# Is it possible to load python variable from another already running process?

Tags: python

Background:

- One process using python `code.interact()` that created an interactive shell
- Have something running in the interactive shell, a job generating a list of credentials and saved to a variable.

Issue:
For some reason, the shell hang and cannot finish

Question:
Is it possible to retrieve the variable that saved in the interactive shell?

Ctrl+Z and Kill the process usually will fix the hang issue but I have to rerun it again and lost some already generated information.

Comment: Why do you need an interactive shell? Why not just use `input()` for data entry?

Comment: the entire system was setup to use the shell, and need interactive.

Comment: `code.interact()` is just a wrapper for an input-eval loop. You can write that loop yourself and use `input()` to take interactive input from the user without giving them access to all of Python. Describe your situation more in your question if you need more in-depth help.

Answer (score 0):

Define a dict `data={}` before starting the interactive session, then pass it as a local `code.interact(local={'data':data})`. Save your data in that dict, and all changes will be available after exiting the interactive session.

This works because `interact` doesn't actually start a new process/interpreter.

Comment: First, thanks. I have one defined `local=locals()` will it helps? The issue is I am currently have that running and want to retrieve variable from the running but hang process. I am not asking to modify the code for future run. (I will improve it for sure when this issue resolved)

Comment: The current process isn't "hanging"; `code.interact()` runs within the current process. `locals()` returns the dict of all current local variables, which is probably not want you want/need. I strongly suspect you don't need to be using `code.interact()` if you're trying to input structured data; can you say why `input()` doesn't work in your case?